# Updating Crontab from Dockerfile in flask

Tags: python, docker, flask, cron, scheduled-tasks

In one of the containers in Docker, it's running a flask application with API endpoints exposed. I'm trying to configure a cron by updating crontab file to consume the api on regular intervals.

Dockerfile

```
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.7-nodejs14  
ENV APP /deploy
.....
.......
COPY . /$APP
RUN pip install -e .
EXPOSE 8080
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "postgres" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "  "

/venv/bin/uwsgi app.ini

# Setup a cron schedule
>&2 echo "* * * * * /usr/bin/curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/import_data >/var/log/stdout1.log 2>/var/log/stderr1.log
# This extra line makes it a valid cron" > scheduler.txt

crontab scheduler.txt
cron -f
```

on executing the command

> docker-compose up

There are no updates done to scheduler.txt. I checked the container and none of the files which created from these -scheduler, stdout, stderr . Above postgres operations work while below print statements are also not executed.

Alternatively, This can be done by using a different container for cron and creating a virtual network for these two containers but i want to understand what's going wrong when try to update in same container.
Let me know if more info is required on same.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you did not delete the container instances and used:

```
docker compose stop
```

instead of

```
docker compose down
```

In that case the container will only be stopped and not removed. when then running the compose up command the containers will simpy be restarted and not rebuild/recreated. Note that things that happen inside of the Dockerfile will only be running/changing when first creating the container (assuming that the image was correctly updated).

On your second note I would add that that would be a better solution in my humble opinion. A docker container is typically meant to only do 1 thing. So if this container is running a service and exposing endpoints a second container would be consuming said endpoints on an interval. This separation of functionality is quite easy to setup and makes it clearer which container is in charge of what.